# Zk multiplecomposer using Spring use composer variable in zul

Tags: java, zk

I have a view using a composer which has inside 5 columnChildren each one are the parentComponent of a macroComponent which also uses a composer.

MyView.zul which has 5 columnChildrens

```
<window id="win" apply='com.MyComposerController'>
<portallayout maximizedMode="whole">
    <portalchildren style="padding:5px" width="50%">
        <panel sclass="innerPanel" border="normal">
            <panelchildren>
                <columnlayout>
                    <columnchildren id='columnChildrenForInfo'/><!-PARENT FOR THE MACROURI TEMPLATE->
                </columnlayout>
            </panelchildren>
        </panel>
        <panel sclass="innerPanel" border="normal">
            <panelchildren>
                <columnlayout>
                    <columnchildren id='columnChildrenForPetition'/><!-PARENT FOR THE MACROURI TEMPLATE->
                </columnlayout>
            </panelchildren>
        </panel>
        <panel sclass="innerPanel" border="normal">
            <panelchildren>
                <columnlayout>
                    <columnchildren id='columnChildrenForErrors'/><!-PARENT FOR THE MACROURI TEMPLATE->
                </columnlayout>
            </panelchildren>
        </panel>
    </portalchildren>
    <portalchildren style="padding:5px" width="50%">
        <panel sclass="innerPanel" border="normal">
            <panelchildren>
                <columnlayout>
                    <columnchildren id='columnChildrenForEsperaNoAtendidos'/><!-PARENT FOR THE MACROURI TEMPLATE->
                </columnlayout>
            </panelchildren>
        </panel>
        <panel sclass="innerPanel" border="normal">
            <panelchildren>
                <columnlayout>
                    <columnchildren id='columnChildrenForDocs'/><!-PARENT FOR THE MACROURI TEMPLATE->
                </columnlayout> 
            </panelchildren>
        </panel>
    </portalchildren>
</portallayout>
```

Latter i create in each columnChildren the following macroUri template
MyViewDetail.zul

```
<zk>
                            <panel>
                                <panelchildren>
<listbox id="results" style="margin-right:5px;margin-top:5px;margin-left:5px">

<listhead>
   <listheader/>                                                
   <listheader/>                                                
   <listheader/>                                            
</listhead>                                         
<template name="model">                                                     
<listitem onClick='$composer.listitemOnClick(event);'>
    <listcell/>
    <listcell/>
    <listcell/>                                         
 </listitem>                                            
</template>                                     
</listbox>                                  
</panelchildren>
</panel>    
</zk>
```

this macroComponent is mapped in lang-addon.xml like this

```
<component>
    <component-name>composerDetailController</component-name>
    <component-class>DetailController</component-class>
    <macro-uri>myViewDetail.zul</macro-uri>
</component>
```

Also the detail composer is a spring bean which i retrieve like this

```
<bean id="composerDetailControllerBean" class="...." autowire="byName" scope="prototype"/>
```

I bind it like this.

```
    final DetailController composerDetailControllerBean = (DetailController)SpringUtil.getBean("composerDetailControllerBean");//EXTRACT IT FROM SPRING CONTAINER
    composerDetailControllerBean.setParent(columnChildren);//EACH DETAIL CONTROLLER HAS A COLUMN CHILDREN AS A PARENT
    detail.afterCompose();
    detail.inicializa();//SOME BUSINESS LOGIC
```

Everything is working like a charm but i had a problem as you can see in the template there is a listitem which doesn't have a id because if i put a id a NONUNIQUEIDINSPACE exception is thrown but i need to listen the onClick method on it i have try the following

```
onClick='$composer.listitemOnClick(event);'
```

But the composer variables points it to the first composer i mean the MyView.zul composer and i have the method and the Business logic in the template composer DetailController but as i dont do this

```
<div id="compA" apply="some.package.ComposerA">
   <div id="compB" apply="some.package.ComposerB"/> i dont use apply in the detailComposer i bind it through lang-addon.xml file
</div>

<div apply="some.package.ComposerA">
   <custom-attributes composerName="myCompA"/>i dont use apply in the detailComposer i bind it through lang-addon.xml file i cannot use customAttributes
</div>
```

I mean i dont set a explicit name to the detail composer and i dont know how to referred it to it in the zul code

i cannot map the composer name to a variable the only thing i did was this try to set a composerName using custom-attributes trying to accomplish the custom-name by custom-attributes aforementioned

lang-addon.xml file

```
<component>
    <component-name>composerDetailController</component-name>
    <component-class>DetailController</component-class>
    <macro-uri>myViewDetail.zul</macro-uri>
  <custom-attribute>
     <attribute-name>composerName</attribute-name>
     <attribute-value>composerDetail</attribute-value>
  </custom-attribute>               
</component>

'$composerDetail.listitemOnClick(event);'
```

Trying to map the custom attribute-name in the lang-addOn and use it in the zul but without success.

I get Caused by: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `$composerDetail.listitemOnClick(event);'' : Attempt to resolve method: listitemOnClick() on undefined variable or class name: $composerDetail : at Line: 14 : in file: inline evaluation of:`             $composerDetail.listitemOnClick(event);'' : $composerDetail .listitemOnClick ( event )

I also try this in the MyViewDetail.zul

```
<zk>
    <custom-attributes composerName="composerDetail"/>
</zk>
```

But not works neither.

In resume i dont know to set a name to the detailComposer and i cannot use it in the MyViewDetail.zul

Comment: To avoid your nonuniqueid you can simply add a component where the zk tag is who implements the idspace interface. If non suitable, create yourself a component who extends div and implements idspace. No extra code needed.

Comment: i just add the listbox inside a div but the nonunique exception still arise i need to implement a custom element like Div extending IdSpace? i think div already implements IdSpace why doesnt work?

Comment: div doesn't implement idspace => https://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/7.0.2/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/IdSpace.html but now I see the javadoc, try `<idspace>`